# Assistance required with ManifestResourceInfo class

Tags: module, manifest

Please can someone provide a situation where the ReferencedAssembly property is not null, I assume that this corresponds to ResourceLocation.ContainedInAnotherAssembly.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0):

ReferencedAssembly will be non null if a resource name is passed to GetManifestResourceInfo that is not the name of a resource embedded in or linked to the assembly and the AppDomain ResourceResolve event has been handled and returns an Assembly that does contain a resource by that name.
The ResourceResolve event will also be raised when using the ResourceManager with satellite assemblies and using the GetString, GetObject and GetStream methods even if the satellite assembly for the provided culture exists in a correct location.